# See all commits from the begin of a branch (see only current branch)

Tags: git

Exists a way to "git log" all commit of current branch from here to the moment we'd created this branch? A sort of "$ git log --current-branch ..."

```
* b137094 Alter this stuff
* b2046b6 Change that stuff
* e6fd3b8 Hello world
* 31f3922 Lol
* d44552a ROTFL
*   7050d07 Hey you the rock steady crew
|\ 
| *   d8a9fcf Queens
| |\
* | | c1d6a37 Bluvertigo
* | | 83a7565 Luciano Ligabue
* | |   cfe48b0 Vasco Rossi
|\ \ \
. . . .
. . . .
```

Watching this graph, what I mean is the same result of

```
$ git log --oneline --graph 7050d07..HEAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that `git log 7050d07..HEAD` "means" `git log HEAD ^7050d07` where the prefix `^` is like a short-term `--not`.  This may not make sense yet; see below, and study the documentation for [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).  This is key to understanding the two git aliases below.)

Git does not have a notion of "when a branch was created".  A branch name is simply a label that moves; and more specifically, a local branch is a name moves automatically as new commits are added while on that branch.  So you can't quite get what you asked for, but you might be able to get what you want.

Git does have what I refer to as a "branch structure": a piece of the commit graph.  It looks to me like what you want here is a `git log` that stops when the branch-structure has a fork, i.e., stops just before the first commit that has two parents.  But it's not clear whether this is *really* what you want.  For instance, consider this graph:

```
               *
              / \
... o--o--*--*   *--*   <-- br1
        \     \ /
         \     *
          \
           o--o   <-- br2
```

where `br1` and `br2` are actual branch labels.  There's a fork-and-join in branch `br1` and you might want your `git log` to show all (but only) the `*`-ed commits.  On the other hand, maybe you want only the single end `*` commit.

I have an alias that does the former, using the branch labels and `git for-each-ref`:

```
[alias]
    ltf = !git log HEAD --not $(git for-each-ref \
            --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ | \
            grep -v "^$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)$") --not
```

(The second `--not` is usually unnecessary: it reverses the effect of the first `--not` so that, e.g., a tag-name argument can add more commits, instead of subtracting commits.  Also, the name `ltf` is from a vague idea I had and is not very meaningful, but it's what's still in my `~/.gitconfig`...)

The idea here is to use `for-each-ref` to produce all local branch names (in short form), discard the current branch if we're on one (`grep -v` with the name from `git symbolic-ref`) , and use those branch names to exclude any commits on other branches.

(Any additional arguments are tacked on to the alias as usual, so `git ltf --oneline --graph` works here.)

If you really do want to exclude all commits starting from the first merge (two-or-more-parent) commit and working backwards, the trick here to use `git rev-list` with `--merges` or `--min-parents=2` (these are the same selectors) to locate it:

```
git rev-list --merges -1 HEAD
```

That's the commit-ID to supply with `--not` (or a prefix `^`, but if there is no such rev this goes awry, so `--not` is superior here):

```
[alias]
    ltm = !git log HEAD --not $(git rev-list --merges -1 HEAD) --not
```

(Again, the second `--not` reverses the effect of the first `--not`, just as in the `ltf` alias above.)  So with this alias, `git ltm --graph --oneline` would produce:

```
* b137094 Alter this stuff
* b2046b6 Change that stuff
* e6fd3b8 Hello world
* 31f3922 Lol
* d44552a ROTFL
```

(The `--graph` here is guaranteed to be boring since there are no forks.)

Comment: Thank you "$ git log HEAD --not $(git rev-list --merges -1 HEAD)"

Comment: Yes, although the second will behave incorrectly if there are no merges in the history behind `HEAD` (since `..HEAD` means `HEAD..HEAD` which is empty).